# Spring JDBC template ROW Mapper is too slow

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a db fetch call with Spring `jdbcTemplate` and rows to be fetched is around 1 millions. It takes too much time iterating in result set. After debugging the behavior I found that it process some rows like a batch and then waits for some time and then again takes a batch of rows and process them. It seems row processing is not continuous so overall time is going into minutes. I have used default configuration for data source.  Please help.

[Edit]

Here is some sample code

```
this.prestoJdbcTempate.query(query, new RowMapper<SomeObject>() {
            @Override
            public SomeObject mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rowNum) throws SQLException {

                System.out.println(rowNum);
                SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
                obj.setProp1(rs.getString(1));
                obj.setProp2(rs.getString(2));
                ....
                obj.setProp8(rs.getString(8));
                return obj;
            }
    });
```

Comment: It takes time to move one million rows over the network. What you see as "batching" is actually the driver requesting more rows over the network into its own buffer. It doesn't make sense to do it continuously due to the network overhead.
What's the idea of mapping a million rows anyways? Do you need all those objects in the memory at the same time? Also show your code.

Comment: Use forward only resultset. This will be useful in fetching these millions of rows. Also set the Mode readonly.

Comment: @Kayaman I need the results to show on UI, So I need all objects in memory at same time, also the sample code is given now

Comment: @sarvesh No you don't. Nobody will look at million objects on any UI. That's why paging and filtering is used.

Comment: @sarvesh use pagination concept instead. Playing with million records at a time is not a good idea.

Comment: @Kayaman You are right. But currently this is the case, are there any optimizations that I could do to make it fast.

Comment: It will never be fast it can be faster by using the tips from @ViswanathL. You could also improve the fetch size limiting the amount of roundtrips to the database.

Answer (score 5):

As most of the comments tell you, One mllion records is useless and unrealistic to be shown in any UI - if this is a real business requirement, you need to educate your customer.

Network traffic application and database server is a key factor in performance in scenarios like this. There is one optional parameter that can really help you in this scenario is : **fetch size** - that too to certain extent

Example :

```
Connection connection = //get your connection
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.setFetchSize(1000); // configure the fetch size
```

Most of the JDBC database drivers have a low fetch size by default and tuning this can help you in this situation. **But beware ** of the following.

- Make sure your jdbc driver supports fetch size
- Make sure your JVM heap setting ( -Xmx) is wide enough to handle objects created as a result of this.
- Finally, select only the columns you need to reduce network overhead.

In spring, `JdbcTemplate` lets you set the `fetchSize`